# If statement in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, ejs

Actually, my layout.ejs code looks like this :

```
    <!-- begin:: Page -->
      <div class="m-page">
        <%- partial('./partials/topnav.ejs') %>
        <!-- begin::Body -->
        <div class="m-body">
          <%- partial('./partials/leftnav.ejs') %>
          <div class="m-wrapper">
            <%- body %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end:: Body -->
        <%- partial('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
      </div>
      <!-- end:: Page -->
      <%- partial('./partials/side.ejs') %>
```

I want to use a different controller in the navbars and body, so I divided the view like that.

Now I want the login page to be different (no navbars at all). I tried to hide the navbars with ng-show, but it flickers and I tried to stop that flickering but I still see the left bar for a fraction of seconds which is really bothering.

So I want to try to display only the body if the location of the page is /login. I cannot use a controller for this, because the ones already in use for the navbars and body section would be in conflict.

I would like to use something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var path = this.window.location.pathname;
</script>

...


<% if (path == '/login') { %>
  <%- body %>
<% } else{ %>
  ..the previous code..
<% } %>
```

But that gets a "path is not defined" error.
So I looked around for information about EJS if statements but at best it always falls in the else condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `path` variable that holds the proper value you need.

Therefore create it in your corresponding controller  and pass it to your view like follows:

```
res.view(pathToYourView, {  path: yourPath, ... });
```